# Redux RTK Query: How to return hard-coded data models?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am using Redux RTK Query and I have the following way of connecting FE with the BE:

```
export const subscriptionServiceApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "...",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: ...,
    prepareHeaders: ...,
  tagTypes: [...],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getSomeData: builder.query<QuoteRes, string>({
      query: (param_id) => `example/${param_id}`
    }),
  })
})
```

This all works well, as long as I have server up and running.
But not all endpoints are ready on the server side (and I have the format of data models for them). The code above, places a GET request to `{baseUrl}/example/{param_id}` and this returns the response `{ some_field: some_value }`.

Now, assuming that we don't have server ruining at all, is there an easy way inside of the `getSomeData` code block, to return hard-coded data model? For example, something like:

```
export const subscriptionServiceApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "...",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: ...,
    prepareHeaders: ...,
  tagTypes: [...],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getSomeData: { some_field: some_value }
  })
})
```

I don't want to have any BE work, and I just need to make FE work with hard-coded data models. I can do this by exporting the data models and importing them inside of the react components, but if I do that, later I need to go back to the code and re-work the part where FE connects with BE. My concerns is, that this should be done in a easy and reusable way, that is why I need the connections are already simulated with Redux RTK Query and once FE work is done, I can just comment / uncomment the lines under `getSomeData` and the data will be replaced with the data from the BE, without a need of doing further adjustments.

What will be the proper way to return the hard-coded models under the `getSomeData` section?

Answer (score 0):

While you technically *can* do that using `queryFn`, I highly recommend using something like [mock service worker](https://mswjs.io/) to fake an external API temporarily. That way, you can write the "final" RTK Query code and just toggle mock APIs on demand without changes to your application code.